# HDInsight HBASE REST request fails (within Vnet)

Tags: rest, azure, hbase, azure-hdinsight

I try to send a REST Request to my HDInsight HBase database from a node.js application within a VNET in azure.
I'm able to ping the corresponding HDInsight HBase Server on its IP adress but its not possible to ping the headnode based on the DNS Suffix with:

```
ping headnode0.<dns suffix>
```

Therefore I'm also not able to send a REST request to the workernodes with the following command:

```
https://workernode0.<clusterdnsuffix>:8090/<table>/<schema>
```

In order to setup the Cluster and the VNet i followed the following article:

[HowTo HBase Cluster in Vnet](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hbase-provision-vnet/)

Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks already for your help

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas Based on your description, I don't know your node.js application whether hosted on Azure. So per my experience, I have two suggestions for the possible scenarioes.

1. If the node app was hosted on Azure, please make sure it was deployed to the sample resource group with your HDInsight HBase. You can try to refer to the article [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/) to configure the VNet for communication with HBase.
2. If the node app was an on-premise deployment, you need to [extend the HDInsight capabilities by using Azure Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network/).

For being sure the HDInsight server can be accessed, I suggest that you need to use the command `ssh` instead of `ping` because of NSG default deny ping with the ICMP protocol which is not permitted through the Azure load balancer. Please see the article [Use SSH with Linux-based Hadoop on HDInsight from Windows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-linux-use-ssh-windows/) to know how to connect.